# Integer square matrix in java

Tags: java

I have integer square matrix. I need to find maximum element in every row and change it with main diagonal element.

My variant:

```
    public class matrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr={{4,3,5},
                    {6,7,1},
                    {9,8,2}};
        int max;
        int temp;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            max=0;
            for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
            if(max<arr[i][j]){
                max=arr[i][j];

            for(int k=0; k<arr.length; k++){    
                if(i==k){
                    temp=arr[i][k];
                    arr[i][k]=arr[i][j];
                    arr[i][j]=temp;
                }
            }
            }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

At the end I must have this `array:`

```
5 3 4
6 7 1
2 8 9
```

But it makes mistake on the second row and show like:

```
5 3 4 
7 6 1 
2 8 9
```

Where I make mistake

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by main diagonal element.

Comment: Agree with @AnuragJoshi. There are more than one element in the main diagonal.

Comment: Main diagonal elements are 4,7,2.

Comment: In first row it must change 4 with 5. In second row don't touch 7 because 7 is maximum element of the row and main diagonal element. And change 9 and 2, because 9 maximum element, but 2 main diagonal element.

Comment: If you print your max values at each iteration you realise they are 4,5,6 and 9 respectively. That means in your second row it detects 6 as the largest element rather than 7. That should give you a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in your loops

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    max=0;
    for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
        if(max<arr[i][j]){
            max=arr[i][j];
            for(int k=0; k<arr.length; k++){    
                if(i==k){
                    temp=arr[i][k];
                    arr[i][k]=arr[i][j];
                    arr[i][j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see that that you find the `max` and then go into the `swap` loop.

Whereas you should find the `max` of the `row` first, then try to swap them. So something like this instead.

```
//Iterate through the rows.
for(int i=0; i<arr[0].length; i++){
    max=0;
    int m = 0;
    //find the max of the row.
    for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
        if(max<arr[i][j]){
            max=arr[i][j];
            m = j; //Store the column of where the max is.
        }
    }
    //Swap the two numbers
    for(int k=0; k<arr[i].length; k++){    
        if(i==k){
            temp=arr[i][k];
            arr[i][k]=arr[i][m];
            arr[i][m]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```